# Are there any background ssd to hdd mirroring solutions?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

Looking for something like RAID 1 because its invisible to the end user. Can't use RAID 1 since I want to use a HDD for the mirror drive and it would probably slow things down.

Its not like the SSD is in constant heavy use though, the HDD would have plenty of time to catch up. I just don't want it hindering the performance while otherwise still behaving exactly like RAID 1.

Are there any hardware solutions that provide this?

Comment: Would it be a thing to just copy data with a script in task scheduler everytime?

Comment: @DylanRz That's what I'm doing right now but its annoying, I don't keep a regular schedule and have ~200GB to back up every day so the subtle stuttering gets in my way quite a bit.

Comment: maybe an incremental copy is a possibility. or is it 200GB of new data?

Comment: that is the incremental backup, hosting some heavy lifting here